# Moving background image with Css e jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a background image (larger than the page) positioning
when the mouse move over it and I did, but I would like that when moving
the mouse position relative to image position doesn't change

i.e. in the example below if mouse is over a letter, when moving the
background image the mouse remain on the same letter

but the percentage is not correct

```
var newvalueX = e.pageX / $(window).width() *100;
var newvalueY = e.pageY / $(window).height() *100;
```

working example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pazzZG/

any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Your codepen example does not display anything for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move an image according to the mouse cordinates using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733570/move-an-image-according-to-the-mouse-cordinates-using-jquery)

Comment: now it's working well (in FF and Chrome) for me, are you sure? I have some problems only in Edge...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use percentages at all. Keep track of the mouse's coordinates in the previous `mousemove` event, calculate the difference between those coordinates and the coordinates of the current event, and add that difference to the background's position.

Comment: great idea! take a look at codepen example, now it seems pretty good!